# How would you make a Get Started View in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, appdelegate

I'm trying to make a app that i think needs a guide before use but I'm getting a problem when restarting the app and it goes back to the Get Started View not the Main View (UIViewController) I've got a plist setup where it saves a bool if the user taps Start App its saves a YES bool but when you start the app for the first time its set by default to A NO Bool. heres the code from the appDelegate
from 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GetStartedCheck.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
BOOL myBool = [[myDict objectForKey:@"alreadyUsedApp"] boolValue];
[myDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
  if (myBool == NO)
   {
       self.startedViewController = [[GetStartedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetStartedViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   }
   else if (myBool == YES)
   {
      self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   }

} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

if (myBool == NO)
{
   self.window.rootViewController = self.startedViewController;
}
else if (myBool == YES)
{
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

is there any tutorial I can read and follow or anyone that can give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this,it is easy

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL myBool = YES;
    id exist = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstRun"];
    if(exist==nil){
        myBool = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstRun"];
    }

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (myBool == NO)
        {
            self.startedViewController = [[GetStartedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetStartedViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }
        else if (myBool == YES)
        {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }

    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }

    if (myBool == NO)
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.startedViewController;
    }
    else if (myBool == YES)
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```